# How to connect to postgresql using perl

Tags: perl, postgresql

```
use DBI;
my $db_host = 'localhost';
my $db_user = 'postgres';
my $db_pass = '12345';
my $db_name = 'postgres';
my $db = "dbi:pg:dbname=${db_name};host=${db_host}";
$dbh = DBI->connect($db, $db_user, $db_pass,{ RaiseError => 1, AutoCommit => 0 }) || die "Error connecting to the database: $DBI::errstr\n";
my $query = "SELECT * FROM random_table";
$ref = $dbh->selectcol_arrayref($query);
print join("\n", @$ref);
```

When I execute this file. I get an Error. It Says:

> DBD::pg initialisation failed: Can't locate object method "driver" via package "DBD::pg"

Do I need to install some driver to connect to the database..?

Comment: For a start you must `use strict` and `use warnings`, and declare `$dbh` and `$ref` as you use them

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's `dbi:Pg`, not `dbi:pg`. Case matters.

Comment: And it's `PostgreSQL`, not `postgresql`, which is likely to be the source of the mistake. I guess that's why the better programmers get so heated about the difference between `perl` and `Perl`: it *makes a difference*. And the first thing to do if you get a message like `Can't locate object method "driver" via package "DBD::pg"` is think *did I spell this right?*